# Django alpha numeric validation in form fields

Tags: django-forms, validation, django-views, django-validation

I want to perform  a field validation,but the conditions are

1)The field should have 10 character.

2)off these 1st 5 character should be alphabets and next 5 character should be numeric digits

I performed validation for maximum length check,but rest of the thing how to perform.Is that can be done on a single "if" condition.

I am searching for the logic in google for performing that,but not got any idea.Can any one help me to perform the same.

forms.py for length check

```
def clean_bookref(self):
        cd=self.cleaned_data
        bookref=cd.get('bookref')

        if len(bookref)<10 and re.match(r'[A-z0-9]+', bookref):
            raise forms.ValidationError("Should be 10 digits")

        return bookref
```

I am using this code to do but it is not working.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could use something like his:

```
def clean_bookref(self):
    cd=self.cleaned_data
    bookref=cd.get('bookref')

    if not re.match(r'^[A-Za-z]{5}[0-9]{5}$',bookref) :
        raise forms.ValidationError("Should be of the form abcde12345")

   return bookref
```